# xargs: Operation not permitted when calling bash script from fswatch event

Tags: terminal, bash, permission, script

I'm trying to watch a certain folder and run a script if there is a change to the folder. For this, I'm using below `fswatch` command (OS is Monterey [12.0.1]):

```
fswatch -o ~/Desktop/iosBuildZips | xargs -n1 -I{} ~/Desktop/scripts/script.sh
```

as per the answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515730/is-there-a-command-like-watch-or-inotifywait-on-the-mac%5D).

`fswatch` successfully registers a file change in the defined folder, but there is an error when fswatch tries to call `script.sh`:

```
xargs: /Users/myusername/Desktop/scripts/script.sh: Operation not permitted
```

---

**Screenshot**

[image]

---

I'm not that familiar with macOS, so I tried using ''chmod 777'' on all involved folders.

But this produces the same error.

**Screenshot**

[image]

---

I also get the error when I precede the fswatch command with sudo...

**Why am I getting this error, and how can I fix it?**

I don't think it's relevant what is in `script.sh`, since I get the same error even if `script.sh` contains only one `echo abc` command, but for completeness, here is the contents of `script.sh`.

```
echo Unzipping received build file
unzip ~/Desktop/iosBuildZips/iosBuild.zip -d ~/Desktop/iosBuild
cd ../iosBuild
pod install
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Do you have execute permission to the script itself (not the directory it's in)? Does adding a shebang line (e.g. `#!/bin/bash`) to the beginning of the script help? What about putting it in the top of your home directory instead of the Desktop subdirectory (note: Desktop, Documents, Downloads, and a few other locations are considered private, and have special access restrictions which can cause trouble under complicated circumstances)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why `xargs` returns `Operation not permitted` is that `script.sh` **doesn't have the execute bit set**.

**How do I set the execute bit?**

To make the script executable, simply run:

```
chmod a+x ~/Desktop/scripts/script.sh
```

which sets the execute bit (`x`) for all (`a`) users.

**What is the execute bit anyway?**

UNIX-like operating systems traditionally use a "mode" system to, among other things, describe whether a file is readable, writable or executable. In this context, it's usual to talk about the "execute bit" to describe whether a file is executable.

To see the mode of a file, simply run `ls -l`: the mode is coded in the  first block of information displayed. For example, if you run `ls -l /bin/cp`, you will see that the output looks similar to this:

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   152672 May  9 23:30 /bin/cp
```

In the example above, `-rwxr-xr-x` is the file mode, which in this particular case makes the file readable and executable for all, and writable for the owner, that is, the `root` user.

For more information on file modes and how to interpret them, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File-system_permissions and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod.

Answer (score 1):

~/Desktop is a protected folder.

xargs can't read the script, that's what "Operation not permitted" means.

```
$ # terminal does not have full disk access...
$
$ echo abc | xargs -n1 -I{} ~/Desktop/scripts/test.sh
ksh: /Users/mwilson/Desktop/scripts/test.sh: cannot open [Operation not permitted]
$
$ # give terminal full disk access...
$
$ echo abc | xargs -n1 -I{} ~/Desktop/scripts/test.sh
test!
$
```

Give xargs the power to read the script or don't store the script in a protected folder.

Comment: "Give xargs the power to read the script", how?

Comment: Thanks Marc Wilson, but I had already tried that to no avail. However, I found a solution and am making an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why (since I am not too familiar with zshell, bash, and so on), but it seems I had to call `script.sh` from `bash`. i.e.:

```
fswatch -o ~/Desktop/iosBuildZips | xargs -n1 -I{} bash ~/Desktop/scripts/script.sh
```

Now the commands in `script.sh` actually execute when there is a change in `~/Desktop/iosBuildZips`.

Comment: If someone with an understanding of why it works this way wants to expand on this answer, please do.

Comment: Could it be that `~/Desktop/scripts/script.sh` doesn't have the executable bit set (that would explain that you need to prepend `bash` to it)? If that's the case, you can set it with `chmod a+x ~/Desktop/scripts/script.sh`.

Comment: @jaume yep, that was it, thanks! Feel free to add this as an answer if you want and I'll mark it as accepted!

Comment: I'm glad it helped. I've added an answer with provided some background information about the execute bit and file modes.